# Check Java heap space in Spring controller

Tags: java, spring, heap-memory

Have an issue with limited heap space and concurrent requests blowing the heap. Is it a good idea/programming practice to check for the maxmemory and return the requests with appropriate error message at the Spring Controller level?

Comment: use tools like `jstat -gc pid`

Answer (score 0):

With pure java

```
Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
//used memory
 runtime.totalMemory() - runtime.freeMemory()
//free memory
 runtime.freeMemory();
//available memory
 runtime.totalMemory();
//Maximum available memory
 runtime.maxMemory();
```